# Help with sound statistics methodology to report partial positive results

Tags: multiple-regression, smoothing

I am in the process of writing up a manuscript. 
Our hypothesis: Longer duration of medication use (month) is associated with higher apnea-hypopnea index (AHI; a marker for obstructive sleep apnea severity).

Multivariable and Univariate linear regression analysis between AHI and different variables did not reveal any significant association between AHI with medication use duration even before or after controlling for the other variables.  Regression did show a strong correlation with body mass index (BMI), as expected.

Nonlinear associations using locally weighted scatterplot smoothing (LOWESS) is posted.

[image]
[image]

After playing with the data in different ways and stratifying by sex, I found that relationship between concurrent palatal implant (PI) use duration and AHI in men appears to follow an inverted V-shaped function as shown. After trying different cutoffs, I found that one of them produces statistically significant high positive correlation with AHI in men within that time frame but not the one specified in the study.

I know that seems to be data driven rather than hypothesis driven. 
What is the best way to present the positive findings in an interesting and sound statistical method? Otherwise, I may need to submit it mainly for the descriptive data rather than the proved hypothesis!